# error: non-const lvalue reference w.r.t. boost::multi_array and foreach

Tags: c++, boost, clang, llvm

so I have created a

```
boost::multi_array<Tile *, 2> map;
```

and I want to

```
for(auto&i:map) { i->reveal(); }
```

but clang/llvm says

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'sub_array<...>' cannot bind to a
      temporary of type 'sub_array<...>'
```

pointing at the '`i`' of "`auto&i`" as the culprit.

I see other discussions of errors similar to this, but I'm unsure of where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of a N-dimensional array are (N-1)-dimensional array views.

This is what the `sub_array<...>` temporary means. So, you will want to:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

struct Tile {
    void reveal(){}
};

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<Tile*, 2> map;

    for (auto row: map) {
        for (auto& col: row) {
            col->reveal();
        }
    }
}
```

> *Note you can also bind to an rvalue-reference (`auto&&`) which is perhaps better in the general case, but should not make a difference here.*

If you insist you can go "directly" to the storage backend:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i< map.num_elements(); ++i) {
    map.data()[i]->reveal();
}
```

But that breaks the abstractions (be very sure you understand how strides, storage order, base offsets all combine before you do this).

Comment: I must say: the docs for boost are very unclear on this topic.  In this instance, they implied that boost was providing an iterator over _all_ the array items.  It often seems like boost is very clique-ish with information being withheld at many turns.

Comment: It's being with-held by what clique? Where do the clique go for the information? I'm not sure where you found that the iterators would be across all elements.

Comment: The first google lands me at [_"This is an iterator over the values of A. If NumDims == 1, then it models Random Access Iterator. Otherwise it models Random Access Traversal Iterator, Readable Iterator, Writable Iterator, and Output Iterator."_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#:~:text=if%20numdims%20%3D%3D%201%2C%20then%20it%20models%20random%20access%20iterator.%20otherwise%20it%20models) (where each named concept is its own hyperlink)

Comment: So, my analysis is [a bit more pedestrian](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor): Boost are libraries contributed by developers for developers, and they are typically not the best at writing user documentation. What you get in return is high-quality, vetted libraries that you can build upon. The value is there. I'm actually usually much more concerned about the state of _standard library_ documentation (or the utter lack thereof)